# is there any method to get the full path str from a file handle?

Tags: c

i did the following

```
HANDLE hFile = FindFirstFile(path,&fileData);
```

if it is a file(not a dir):

```
printf("<File>\t : %s\n",fileData.cFileName);
```

example output:

```
<File>    : abc.txt
```

but how can i get the full path of this abc.txt?
i tried "GetFinalPathNameByHandle"  and use GetLastError()
it tell me that the HANDLE is invalid
or is there any method to help me get the full path of file?

Comment: In the call to `FindFirstFile()` you pass the directory to look for files. So you just have to combine that directory with the filename.

Comment: i did use this method to finish the task, but i would like to know how can i use a handle to get the full path

Comment: In general, you cannot go from a file descriptor (or pointer, or handle) to a named file at all. It is possible that the "file" does not exist in the file system.

Comment: @RoyC Is there a reason you would prefer to use the handle as opposed to appending the file name to its directory path?

Answer (score 0):

As @Wimmel mentioned in the comments, you already know the directory of the file, so you just need to combine the directory path with the file name.

```
char fullpath[MAX_PATH];
snprintf(fullpath, sizeof fullpath, "%s\\%s", path, fileData.cFileName);
printf("Full path: %s\n", fullpath);
```